# Flexbox game - can't use order and align self

Tags: css, flexbox

here's the link of the game: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

I have a problem with level 24, the last level: The yellow frogs have to go inside yellow lilypads while the green frogs and a red frog have to inside green lilypads and a red lilypad. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flex-flow: column-reverse wrap-reverse;
justify-content: center;
align-content: space-between;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you done level 1 to 23?

I just played around and followed the previous levels and came up with this:

```
flex-direction: column-reverse;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
align-content: space-between;
justify-content: center;
```

Fun game though.

Comment: yea I have done those, but lvl 24 got me very confused...yeah, it is great for understandng flexbox